# Can't find JavaScriptCore.framework in Xcode link libaries

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to link the `JavaScriptCore.framework` since you have to do it manually as of React Native 0.58. I tried following the steps to "Link Binary With Libraries" but did not find any frameworks in the dropdown that appears. Do you know what setting I need to set for this to populate? I know on other projects (workspace for React Native), it automatically appears.

[image]

Comment: You need to enter a search query for it to populate, just type "J" and you'll see it under iOS 12.1

Answer (score 1):

You can find it from the path below.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework